# Visit a cell more than once using BFS

Tags: graph-theory, breadth-first-search

I'm trying to solve a problem of a maze where I have to get all the coins in a 2D grid and print the shortest path just using Breadth-First Search. This algorithm marks as visited the nodes (cells) as it's finding the path, but this problem requires to visit the cells more than once, so I cannot mark them as visited.

This is the basic pseudocode of BFS based on **ICS 161**:

```
unmark all vertices
    choose some starting vertex x
    mark x
    list L = x
    tree T = x
    while L nonempty
    choose some vertex v from front of list
    visit v
    for each unmarked neighbor w
        mark w    // I cannot mark as visited as long I have to visit that neighbor again
        add it to end of list
        add edge vw to T
```

How can I re-visit a cell without having to mark it as visited?

Or how can I mark some cells that I know that they're not part of the shortest path? So the algorithm doesn't have to add unnecesary edges.

Comment: I believe you want to visit the node more than once to find the optimal path, in that case, try to use iterative deepening search or is there any other purpose why you want to visit node more than once?

Comment: Because the shortest path to collect all the coins can involve visiting a cell more than once. For example, if an empty space is '.', my character is 'A' and a coin is 'C' in a 1x5 grid:

**C.AC**

The shortest path would be Right, Left, Left, Left.

Comment: Do you have to specifically use BFS? The A* algorithm might be something for you to look into @KimDoe

Answer (score 0):

Though I am still a little bit confused about your question, here's some of my suggestions.
To find the shortest path using BFS, prim's algorithm might be the best option.

This a brief description for how prim algo works.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/prims-minimum-spanning-tree-mst-greedy-algo-5/

In your case, we need to do few things:

1. do BFS on each edges and find the shortest path for each coins to the rest of the coins and your starting point(BFS will always lead you to the shortest path)

Now we have edges, and vertex, and we can do Prim's Algo!

2. Start at the starting points, and do prim algo

Hope this helps you